# Expand div according to the inner text

Tags: html, css

I've got the following div elements in my HTML. They act as buttons.

```
  <div id="button-section">
    <!-- Section for function buttons -->
      <div class="fn-button">
      <!-- Function button -->
        <span>My Current Checks</span>
      </div>
      <div class="fn-button">
      <!-- Function button -->
        <span>All Current Checks</span>
      </div>
      <div class="fn-button">
      <!-- Function button -->
        <span>Add New order</span>
      </div>
  </div>
```

This is the CSS that I've used for there elements.

```
 #button-section{
width: 100%;
height: 150px;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
background-color: rgb(229, 229, 255);
 }

 .fn-button{
width: 130px;
height: 50px;
float: left;
margin: 10px 0px 0px 20px;
border-radius: 10px;
background: rgb(111, 111, 111);
box-shadow: inset 1px 4px 12px rgb(0, 0, 0);
text-align: center;
 }

 .fn-button span{
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
color: white;
vertical-align: -17px;
font-size: 20px;
 }
```

The thing is, I need to adjust the width according to the text inside each div element.! for this either I have to define width for each element or find another method. The below image will display my situation of the divs.

[image: Display Error]

How can I dynamically expand the divs according to the inner text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `width` rule from the divs (`width: 130px`).

This ends up looking a little scrunched, but you can fix that with some padding

```
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/zXN6C/